# Can profile pictures be aligned straight on the Winterbash leaderboard?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, winter-bash-2020

On the leaderboard there is a fixed width between the rank and the profile picture, as they both have a fixed padding in CSS.
Can this be adjusted to account for the fact that single digit numbers take less space then double or triple digit numbers do? So that the profile pictures always align nicely.

Thanks on behalf of my OCD.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pics are now aligned (with the exception of your own pic that appears at the top - which may have a ranking with more than two digits, not going to try to align based on that).

> obsessive compulsive
> disorder sufferers may find
> this haiku annoying

Comment: Thx for the quick fix Yaakov, there is however a very small discrepancy left when going from 2 digit numbers to three digit numbers ;) But not as disturbing as this front page was ;)

Comment: You can see here: https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network?page=6

Comment: @Luuklag sorry, but I hope that you will be able to manage with that in place. Not making any more changes here.

Comment: I'll survive, hopefully ;)